# How to Change MenuItems in Unity in One Scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to change the items placed in UI on basis of items clicked on.

User have to click on Name of the game then it will unable the existing item and enable the chapters item to show chapters.

**Note:** I don't need to change scenes, I know how to change scene with buttons.

I have attached the screenshot of the main menu.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a reference of the gameObjects you want to Activate/Deactivate.

Create a [**button**](https://docs.unity3d.com/530/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Button-onClick.html) and use [**GameObject.SetActive**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html) to activate/deactivated the objects you want when the user press it.

You can make the button invisible so the user thinks he's clicking the title but actually he clicks a button.

I Hope this helps. :D

---

I suggest creating a button for every menu interaction in general. 
To handle your buttons OnClickEvents you need to create an empty gameObject on your scene and attach to it a script that your buttoms will use to do whatever you want when you click them.
For example:

```
//You can name your method however you like.

public void ButtomClicked(){
    //Hide the UI on the screen expect the Back button.
    //Show chapters to the player
}
```

Create a button and from the inspector select the Empty Gameobject this script is attached to and then select the ButtomClicked method. When you press the buttom the code in the method will run.

To avoid activating/deactivating all this buttons one by one, you can attach them to a panel(UI element) and activate/deactivate the panel istead. So, lets say you have 3 panels.

The Main menu panel, the Chapters panel and the Options panel.

When the player wants to see the chapters, you diactivate the main menu panel and activate the chapters panel. To make this feel really polished you can add transition animations later on.

This is how i handle my UI without never changing scenes. It gives a really smooth and polished feel to the user.

If you have more quastions about UI, plz watch this [turtorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_RIsfVOqTaE), it helped me a lot to understand the basics.

Comment: I have a button, and that is inactive, could you please let me know how to attach on click event and I have also chapters, do I also need button for each element?

Comment: Thanks, but too many buttons will overwhelm the scene/UI (button for each chapter and each level)

Comment: @EngrUmair I think you didn't understand my answer. You will have 1 button, when you press it, it will show the chapters buttons and hide itself. You can't handle UI without buttons. It's impossible. The only way i can imagine is to have the panels next to each other horizontaly and the user will swipe to change panel. Other than that you can't do anything without buttons.